# Why cant i set X = ord(ripped_function)

Tags: python

i am getting a invalid syntax error, on line 28, where i declare x for my loop. I am kinda new at this so if you could explain why i am getting the error i would much appreciate it

```
def peace():
# ord() function feeds back a int value for the ASCII codes and chr() takes these int's  and turns them back in to char's   
    ripped_function = []  # this is going to hold a string broken down letter by letter
    type_function = []    # this is going to hold the types of char held in the ripped_function list
    ripped_function[:0] = raw_input("This is letter by letter")  # takeing in user entered string

    print(ripped_function[0:len(ripped_function)]) # to see the string broken down

    i = 0
    for i in range(0,len(ripped_function)   # for the entire list 

        x = ( ord(ripped_function[i]) )    # x is supposed to be the  int value that ord() returns

        if (x >= 97) and (x <= 122)  # 97 is lower case 'a' and 122 is lower case 'z'
            type_function[i] = ['lower case letter'] #classifying 
        if (x >= 65) and (x <= 91)   #65 is capital 'A' and 91 is capital 'Z'
            type_function[i] = ['upper case letter'] #classifying
        else:
            type_function[i] = ['THIS NEEDS MORE PROGRAMMING 2343']  #just to let me know where to keep building lose ends with a search code 2343


    print(type_function[0:len(type_function)]) #to see the break down
    return("just keep going")  #because i need a rememinder sometimes
```

Comment: You are missing `:` after your `for` loop

Comment: thank you so much, my head was going to blow up, i had started dissecting my code into pieces. Hope this works thanks a bunch